# HTML - What does data-remote="true" do?

Tags: html

I was just working on a project that was sending an extra request and it was because of `data-remote="true"`. I've seen this line plenty of times before, but I guess I don't really know what it does. I tried Googling it but all that comes up are specific examples where data-remote isn't working for the question asker.

I just want to know what the purpose of `data-remote="true"/"false"` is to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: As above, sounds like some javascript is using that attribute to trigger an ajax request.

Comment: It's just an HTML data attribute, it doesn't do anything by itself. If it's causing some automatic behavior, it's probably related to a framework that you're using.

Comment: There is a JS function that is called on click, and it does contain an AJAX request. I understand that's why one of the requests gets made. But the other request is made depending on whether data-remote="true" is in the <a> tag. I don't understand why that causes a request. Maybe like c-smile mentioned, it has to do with some existing code elsewhere in the project, but I can't find it yet.

Comment: And that's why we use IDEs or good editors because you can look for `remote` string and have them list which files have it in them, without wasting precious time to find it manually. As others pointed out, it's a custom attribute used by something, so there's no doubt that there's an event being bound somewhere that has something to do with that attribute. Alternatively, you can use your browser's dev. console and track the event listeners and check what they do and how.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

data-remote = "true" is used by the Ruby On Rails framework to submit the form/link/button as an ajax request. If you are interested here is the guide discussing how Ruby on Rails works with javascript: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: how does date-remote="true" work like <a href="/blah" data-remote="true">abc</a>  I had thought that data-remote was a rails thing but I see it in the html.  So what is causing the web browser to make the GET request via AJAX rather than the usual method that causes a webpage to load?

Comment: @barlop looks like  data-remote="true" causes rails-ujs javascript library to intercept the click and make an ajax call.. the edgeguides.rubyonrails link shows how that interception is done. (And using coffeescript to javascript converter on what is on mahi's edgeguides link), I see it uses a method like) . `$("a[data-blah]").click(function(e) {...});` . and interception done by rails-ujs is apparently found https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.3/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/remote.coffee

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely not a standard thing.

Usually `data-***` is a custom attribute used on application level. So check in sources of your scripts - it is used by some code.

Answer (score -3):

I was told that `data-remote="true"` is an HTML version of JavaScript's `preventDefault()` method, in that it simply prevents the form from being submitted to the server.

Rails applications along with the jQuery gem generates the global listener:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-remote=true]", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getScript($(this).href())
});
```

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: The attribute `data-remote` by itself does not do anything, it's just a dataset attribute. Rails however uses elements (anchors, forms) marked with this attribute to submit or navigate to them asynchronously.

Comment: @AndréSilva You're right about that. I wasn't implying that the `data-` attribute is only used as a shorthanded `preventDefault()`. The question asked what does `data-remote="true"`, but to address you're point, I've added some details to my original answer, which I still find to be correct.

Comment: This is incorrect, or at best misleading in the way it is worded. If you put `data-remote="true"` on any link or button that action will still take place, just in the background. So a form *is* still being submitted, a url from an `a` tag *is* still being visited, but via ajax. Try it and look at the server log. It only prevents the browser from changing pages.

Comment: Great answer. I would just change the second line to: $.getScript($(this)[0].href);